# How to choose the equally spaced values for temperature variable in R?

Tags: r, splines, epidemiology, environmental-data

I am learning a distributed lag non-linear model. In that, I have to create a cross basis matrix first. For cross-basis, I need to specify the knots at equally spaced values of the temperature variable.

This is the script I am using

```
ktemp <- equalknots(data$temp,nk= ?)
```

What should be the nk value here? How should I choose the value that represents equally spaced values of temperature variable?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking about how the function `equalknots` works: please consult its documentation.  (It isn't clear what the source of this function is or if it is even publicly available.)